# Git merge (or GitHub pull request) doesn't see all the data from the commits

Tags: git, merge, pull-request

I have a project for which I suspect I've done something wrong with a git revert. Sparing the details, but at this point I have :

`master`, `develop` and `move-video-to-task` branch.

`move-video-to-task` is off of `develop` which is off of `master`.

My project is [here](https://github.com/omartin2010/jetson_object_detection/compare/develop...move-video-to-task). Specifically, the issue is that if I compare theses two branches (move-video-to-task), it says there isn't anything to compare. And if you look at some individual files in these respective branches, there are a few changes to compare. Yet locally with `git merge` it doesn't give me the choice of merging changes, nor does it on GitHub.

Any idea what I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the page you linked to:

https://github.com/omartin2010/jetson_object_detection/compare/develop...move-video-to-task

See how, on that page, it suggests that you try "switching the base"? Those words are in blue. They are a link. Click it. Now you'll see this:

https://github.com/omartin2010/jetson_object_detection/compare/move-video-to-task...develop

Is that more like what you were expecting?

As for what happened: You say "move-video-to-task is off of develop". It was, but it seems you merged, perhaps the wrong way (it seems that has happened before), or perhaps you just forgot where you were after the merge. Anyway, after the merge, you were on `develop`, not on `move-video`. You then made a commit. So that newest commit is on `develop`:

```
* commit b1ca78f (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop, origin/HEAD)
| Author: omartin <omartin@live.ca>
| Date:   Mon Apr 20 22:14:56 2020 -0400
| 
|     fixed missing change from video branch
|   
*   commit 8fa08c8
|\  Merge: 6e9a76f 3e09220
| | Author: omartin <omartin@live.ca>
| | Date:   Mon Apr 20 22:12:28 2020 -0400
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'move-video-to-task' into develop
| | 
| * commit 3e09220 (origin/move-video-to-task)
| | Author: omartin <omartin@live.ca>
| | Date:   Mon Apr 20 22:11:34 2020 -0400
| | 
| |     added useless change to allow merging
| | 
* | commit 6e9a76f
| | Author: omartin <omartin@live.ca>
| | Date:   Mon Apr 20 21:59:36 2020 -0400
| | 
| |     added missing constantgit
```

Now, github compare is not identical to `git diff`. If you `git diff` the two branches, there obviously is a difference between them, since they denote different commits. But if you compare them on github in the direction you used, you are asking, "What would happen if I were to do a pull request from `move-video` into `develop`?" And github replies: "Nothing would happen; you can't do a pull request in that direction, because `develop` is already fast-forwarded from `move-video`."